# Android WiFi (sending and receiving data without specifying recipient)

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I want to make an application is via WiFi would send and receive data without sending them to a specific recipient. I explained to the example of a simple chat: The user sends a message via WiFi, but without a specific destination. As a result, his report available to all users nearby. Similarly other users can receive and send messages. I also want to realize the function of repeater, where each user's device not only receives a message from the other devices, and retransmits them to others allowing increase the coverage area of WiFi connection.

But at the moment it is not possible to send data without a specific recipient. The same WiFi Direct necessarily require pairing before data transfer. Can not specify that the recipient is unknown.

Recently I heard the news about the technology WiFi Aware, which involves greater interaction between WiFI devices. Please reply, WiFi Aware allows to do what I described above? Namely - the transfer of data and we will without a clear indication of the recipient and the need to do additional work (eg preliminary pairing between devices).

If WiFi Aware allows to do what I described - when it is expected to release its API? In particular, for Android devices. And if not - you can tell me how to implement what I need? And in general - it is technically possible?

Thank you for your time and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to look into [nsd via wifi-direct](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html). This Network Service discovery via Wifi-Direct. What this helps you to achieve is broadcast information to all listening devices.

On the device which wants to convey the information you `addLocalService` and on the other devices you should `discoverServices`. In the `ServiceInfo` object you can the pass the information you want to communicate to the other devices who are listening for services. Please try to study from the link attached above.

I am not very sure about how repeater will work with this.